# "The iTunes library file cannot be saved. A folder was specified instead of a file." ...what?

Tags: itunes, macos

I just updated to iTunes 11.

Now I get this error:
[image: The iTunes library file cannot be saved. A folder was specified instead of a file.]

Huh? Some Googling turns up people with this problem in iTunes 7 & 8. That was a while ago. They suggested various things, including rebuilding the library (which I am NOT going to do unless it's the only option).

However, my search prompted me to look in my iTunes folder. Yikes:
[image: iTunes folder is full of temp files!]
Most of those temp files appeared on 11/18/12, so this must have been happening before today when I upgraded.

So, is there a good solution? Why might this happen? Is re-building the library the only way? I'd rather not lose my date-added and play-count data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a possible solution that I came across and (initially) it seems to have worked for me:

Quoted from [Apple Support Communities](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4260937?start=0&tstart=0):

> I assume the problem is gone now and here's what I did to get rid of it:
>
> - stop iTunes
> - alt-start iTunes, so it offers 'Create Library' and 'Choose Library'
> - choose 'Create Library' to create a new library (iTunes 1)
> - stop iTunes
> - alt-start iTunes, so it offers 'Create Library' and 'Choose Library'
> - choose 'Choose Library' and chose my main library, which caused me so much pain
>
> since then no more tmp files are left over in the iTunes folder and I hope it stays like this